# How to install Beatbox?

Tags: beatbox

I have a problem with installation of Beatbox music player in Ubuntu 11.10. When I tried to install the software, I could not install it because I needed a lib called libgranite0.

I tried entering the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sgringwe/beatbox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementaryart/elementarydesktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install beatbox
```

But those commands do not work! They required me to have libgranite0 installed but I don't know how to install that. I tried searching in Google but I couldn't find how to install this package.

I want to know if there is a way to install this dependency so that I can install Beatbox media player.

Comment: Please add the exact error you received in the terminal to your question.

Comment: You can find `granite` in elementary-daily PPA. Better just download .deb package or build granite from source, instead adding PPA.

Answer (score 2):

You will need [sqlheavy](https://launchpad.net/~nemequ/+archive/sqlheavy) to use beatbox AFAIK. Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemequ/sqlheavy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install beatbox
```

And if you want to follow `beatbox` development and use latest development release I recommend you to use [elementary-daily](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily) ppa.